# What conditions are necessary for open() to fail, with UDP sockets, on Windows?

Tags: c, windows, sockets, networking, udp

What conditions are necessary for open() to fail, with UDP sockets, on Windows?

Thanks.

Comment: What did you do? Did something fail? What error codes or messages did you receive?

Comment: hah, nothing failed, I want to test something if it were to fail...(prayers are with Christchurch, New Zealand)

Comment: I suppose some kinds of software firewall could reject UDP operations. (Thanks, my wife and I are safe at home.)

Comment: I don't understand. You don't open() a socket, you call socket().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time I've seen that happen is when I didn't initialize WinSock with WSAStartup().

Comment: Can something be configured on the operating system to fail it?